# Undefined reference compilation MITK/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mitk

I need to compile the project of my teacher. This project use MITK, VTK, ITK, CTK and Qt. I had some errors which I managed to correct during compilation. Now, i have an error that I don’t understand and I don’t know how correct that to finish the compilation.

The problem is that I have :
undefined reference to « operator delete(void, unsigned long)@Qt_5 »* in the library libMitkAppUtil.so
We see also it is a link error. As it is a project of my teacher and others teachers I think it is a problem with a version of Qt or something in my computer no like the version of gcc or g++ ?

When I open Qt and i open many files there are three messages nearly of the toolbar :

the code model could not parse an included file, which might lead to incorrect completion and highlighting, for example.
Multiple parse contexts are available for this file. Choose the preferred one from the editor toolbar.
This file is not part of any project. The code model might have issues parsing this file properly.

Maybe there is a link with the error on the terminal ?

Comment: I forgot to add that I use Qt 5.12.9, gcc and g++ 8.4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The use of images as the *only* way to convey messages and logs is *discouraged*. Please post messages **as text** in your question.

Answer (score 0):

do you use `cmake` for the build process?
e.g.

```
cd MITK-build;
cmake ../MITK-source ./;
make -j1
```

Please start the build process in single-thread mode and then attach the standard output text to your reply so that we can look into the problem.

Sometimes problems occur with the `/ep/` part of the build process (e.p. = external projects), there you could '`cd ep/xxx.../; cmake ./;make -j1`' to start individual builds.

HTH,